# AngularJS select directive not working in jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was playing around with some jsfiddle examples and changed it for some tests. Unfortunately it is not working anymore and i have no clue why. Can anyone have a quick look at this fiddle and give me a hint:

http://jsfiddle.net/w8LrL8xr/2/

javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp");

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.fonts = [
    {title: "Arial" , text: 'Url for Arial' },
    {title: "Helvetica" , text: 'Url for Helvetica' }
];
$scope.change= function(option){
    alert(option.title);
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="opt" ng-options="font.title for font in fonts" ng-change="change(opt)">
    </select>

    <p>{{opt}}</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your module definition is incorrect, you need to supply a list of dependencies to init it correctly or an empty `[]` if you have none.

e.g.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

You are also missing a trailing `)` when you register your controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.fonts = [
        {title: "Arial" , text: 'Url for Arial' },
        {title: "Helvetica" , text: 'Url for Helvetica' }
    ];
    $scope.change= function(option){
        alert(option.title);
    };
});
```

**[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/w8LrL8xr/6/)**

Comment: Thanks, sometimes i´m really blind ;)

Comment: Just in addition: Why is this not working? I only added a parent controller: http://jsfiddle.net/w8LrL8xr/7/

Comment: You are missing the closing ) for the other controller. `:)`